# Flat Cat6 RJ45 and boots

Tags: network-adapter, cable

I bought a flat cat6 cable a while back, It promptly got chopped into 2 and now I'm left with a 2 half cables. I bought another cable, which is now in use. I do however have 50 meters of cable. I also have a crimper and know how to use it.

What I do not have is any RJ45 connectors or boots. I would like to order a few (50 or 100) and then make use of my chopped up cable.

What I would like to do is get some boots *that are made for the flat cable* rather than have poorly-fitting square peg (cable) in a round hole scenario.

**Any recommendations about where I could order/buy flat-cable RJ45 / boots would be welcome. I live in BC, Canada. (*Online ordering with delivery would be prefereable)***

Answer (score 0):

Just some quick Googling, and I found this:

- [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B018BCJKE0/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018BCJKE0)

It's flat, It's CAT6, and it looks like it is what you need

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the effort, but I'm not sure if you read the question properly, or if I did not ask it will enough. Either way, I'm not looking for the cable. I'm looking for the end bits **(the RJ-45 connectors that go with the flat cable... And the boots that go with the connectors.)**

Comment: I think the end bits are standard built into the cable or it's the ethernet card in your computer...

Comment: Yes, when you buy a flat cable like the one you linked, they come as a all-in-one unit. Please re-read my question. In the first sentence, it explains why I want the connectors and boots.  You get them for round cables (https://www.amazon.ca/VCELINK-Shielded-Modular-Ethernet-Connector/dp/B0883DNJ2N), I want them for the flat cables.

Comment: I don't know if they sell those...